# How to run a script with Git bash with custom bashrc?

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I am trying to get a bash script to run in git bash while specifying a different .bashrc than the one in my home directory (or none at all) however it is proving an impossible task.

To my understanding this should work:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe " --rcfile .bashrc --login -i C:/Scripts/myscript.sh

However no matter what I try either the --rcfile file flag will be completely ignored or the script will get parse errors because it is not parsed by bash.

The following are my findings:

- --login flag is needed to get the script to be parsed by bash rather than windows command prompt
- --rcfile and also --norc are completely ignored if flags --login is used

I have tried every possible combination I think of, including calling the script within my .bashrc file, swapping the flags around, using the -c flag to run the script command and swapping my .bashrc files around to try using the --norc flag instead.

Is this just a result of shitty bash implementation for windows or am I doing something wrong?

Any help on the matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try sourcing your `.bashrc` inside the script `myscript.sh`.

```
source .bashrc
```

Or

```
. .bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks but that still run my original .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the `-i` flag is overridden by the fact that you provide a script for `bash` to run. Your shell isn't actually interactive, so `--rcfile` is ignored. The only way I can tell to both run a script *and* source an additional file is to use a non-interactive login shell; however, in that case, you are restricted to using `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, or `.profile`, whichever is found first:

```
bash --login myscript.sh
```

There is no `--loginfile` to override the choice of file sourced prior to `myscript.sh`.

---

UPDATE: I forgot about `BASH_ENV`.

```
export BASH_ENV=.bashrc
bash myscript.sh
```

I do not know how you would go about adding `BASH_ENV` to your environment in Git bash.

Comment: Maybe simply using the Windows `set` command; but its scope is the current session (I think; or matbe it's just undocimented), so if you use Bash for other things, too, you can't use that.

Comment: OK I see what you mean. I have managed to create a .bash_profile which checks to see whether a .bashrc file exists in the current directory and sources that that otherwise the one from home directory however the problem is that if the one in the home directory is called .bashrc, it always tries to use that when I start the shell, so I had to call it something different so only the code from .bash_profile runs. Is there any reason this hapens?